# JDBC Driver Loading error

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

below is my simple program of JDBC Oracle Connectivity. Please see and tell me why could I possibly get the error of driver not loading. I have put `odbc14.jar` in libraries.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package databaseconnect;

/**
 *
 * @author compaq
 */
import java.sql.*;

public class Education1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try{
            Class.forName("oracle:jdbc:driver:OracleDriver");
        }catch( Exception e ) {
      System.out.println("Failed to load Oracle driver.");
        }
try{
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","system");
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate("insert into Education(name,rollno) VALUES ('alankrit',1000)");
            System.out.println("Data inserted");
            con.close();


    }   catch(Exception e){
    //     System.out.println(e);
    }

    }

}
```

Comment: Without even seeing it, I am certain your CLASSPATH is wrong.  Print it out and we'll tell you what it should be.

Comment: In class.forName(), use .(Dot) not colon(:). So use Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")

Comment: Can you please share error/exception that you are getting ?

Comment: Why are you using `odbc14.jar`? That is intended for Java 1.4. Are you really using such an outdated Java version?

Comment: *Applications no longer need to explictly load JDBC drivers using Class.forName()*. [Java 7 API DriverManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html)

Comment: @maba Only if you use a JDBC 4 or higher driver, the `ojdbc14.jar` is JDBC 3.0

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the class name as below, replace : with .

```
 Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
```

Driver Implementation class with complete packages name in String format.

So that reflection api can load this class during run time

Comment: The argument to `Class.forName` is a String, not a `Class` object.

Comment: ok sorry . .edited it. .  main thing was the argument is a class with complete path with packages name.

So that reflection api can load this class during run time.

Comment: Hi..changing ':' to '.' worked in class.forName..thanks for the help everyone..Also can u pls tell me why do we require jars and which is the latest one to be used for JDK5??

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
Class.forName("oracle:jdbc:driver:OracleDriver");
```

use

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
```

and make sure you have `odbc14.jar` file in your classpath.

Comment: There is nothing in the question indicating that this is a web application at all. It is a simple application in fact and thus putting it in WEB-INF is not going to work. BTW I did not downvote your answer...